# Stereochemistry of Gabriel Synthesis

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, stereochemistry

I read that the primary amine product of Gabriel Synthesis is a racemic mixture. However, when analyzing the reaction the stereochemical step(s) are all $S_N2$. Thus, I figured if you are careful you can track the stereochemistry of the (or both) $S_N2$ reaction(s). Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: As far as I remember, the Gabriel reaction transforms  *primary* haloalkanes into *primary* amines.  How do you attribute absolute configuration on a primary haloalkane of type $\ce{R-CH2-Br}$ to the Carbon atom just adjacent to the one of Bromine?

Comment: @Buttonwood It works for secondary haloalkanes as well. For example, people use it to make amino acids which are secondary amines (with the exception of glycine).

Comment: @Cocmos So far, my association with the synthesis of amino acids was the Strecker synthesis.  Revisiting the Gabriel synthesis again, I found indeed an entry relevant to your welcomed comment, used in an answer below.  The preparation of glycine with phtalimide, as outline in the *Polish* wikipedia about the same topic, indeed differs in its procedure.

Answer (score 2):

The lower part of the Dutch wikipedia about the [*Gabrielsynthese*](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabrielsynthese) indeed displays an example where this reaction is carried out to yield a secondary amine:

[image]

The original publication ([DOI: 10.1021/jm9804376](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jm9804376?journalCode=jmcmar&quickLinkVolume=42&quickLinkPage=593&selectedTab=citation&volume=42), *J. Med. Chem.*, **1999**, *42*, 593-600) equally includes similar conversions with racemic secondary substrates like (*R*/*S*)-($\pm$)-1-methylpentyl bromide to yield (*R*/*S*)-($\pm$)-*N*-(1-methylpentyl)phthalimide which in turn was then converted into (*R*/*S*)-($\pm$)-(1-methylpentyl)amine hydrochloride.